# PyQt5 MainWindow get postion relative to screen

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Simple QMainWindow implementation and too much time googling I need to know what the XY coordinates for the main window are relative to the screen.  This implementation always shows 0,0:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class TestReportsApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestReportsApp, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('test.ui', self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def showEvent(self, e):
        print(self.geometry())

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = TestReportsApp()
mainWin.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I get the coordinates of the top-left XY position of the main window relative to the screen?

Comment: When do you want to get the position? You are asking for the position when the window is still not displayed, you get the position (0, 0)

Comment: Can't I get the position in the showEvent method??

Comment: No, this method is called before showing itself, it is in charge of doing the necessary things so that it is shown. will be displayed 30 ms later, but to that you must add the time that is used to decode with loadUi(...), in total after 100 ms the window will be shown, try `def showEvent(self, e):
        super(TestReportsApp, self).showEvent(e)
        QTimer.singleShot(1000, lambda: print(self.pos()))`

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you.